# how to declare anonymous type using a variable's value as key in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there anyway to succeed this sample?

```
string[] columns = ["a","b","c","d"];
var headers = from column in columns
select new
{
  title = column,
  filter = new  { column = "select" },
  show = true
};
```

After debug this code block, I see `header.filter.column` property.
How can I see `header.filter.a` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It's likely that whatever problem you have can be solved with a `Dictionary` instead.  But if you really want to do that I think it would require reflection.

Comment: He means to say he wants a property names `a` .. meaning creating dynamic property

Comment: @Reddy Yes, correct point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, since anynonymous types are *anonymous*, but they still exist *at compile time*. So you can not create an anonymous class with runtime member names.
 What you are actually doing is to set a property named `column` with the value `"select"`.

What you can do though is to create a dictionary from your result and access the data with the dictionary:

```
var headerFilterDictionary = headers.ToDictionary(item => item.title, item => item.filter.column);

var columnFilterValue = headerFilterDictionary["a"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you really want to do (at all), but you can make the syntax (mostly) work by using `dynamic`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] columns = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        var headers = from column in columns

                      let c_a = (dynamic)(column == "a" ? new { a = column } : null)
                      let c_b = (dynamic)(column == "b" ? new { b = column } : null)
                      let c_c = (dynamic)(column == "c" ? new { c = column } : null)
                      let c_d = (dynamic)(column == "d" ? new { d = column } : null)

                      select new
                      {
                          title = column,
                          filter = c_a ?? c_b ?? c_c ?? c_d,
                          show = true
                      };

        var filter_0 = headers.ElementAt(0).filter.a;
        var filter_1 = headers.ElementAt(1).filter.b;
        var filter_2 = headers.ElementAt(2).filter.c;
        var filter_3 = headers.ElementAt(3).filter.d;
    }
```

Obviously, this doesn't scale very well; and since it's dynamic, you don't get IntelliSense on `filter`.

This is probably best considered for entertainment purposes only.